# LSTM Keras input and output dimensions

Tags: pandas, numpy, keras, lstm

I have 30 time steps with 26 features, so I would imagine my input into the first layer would be of dimension #_samples x 30 x 26.

One problem I have is that my # of samples varies by the time step. Should I pad to make them uniform?

Another is that I am trying to create the time-indexed 3D array by separating out the dataset into their respective time steps and combining them into a 3D array, but all the different methods I've tried have failed so far.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
def lstm_data_processing(X_data, Y_data):
    num_time_steps = X_data['month_id'].nunique()
    month_ids = X_data['month_id'].unique()
    X_processed = []
    X_processed.reshape(X_data.shape[0], X_data.shape[1], num_time_steps)

    for i in range(num_time_steps):
        month_df = X_data.loc[X_data['month_id'] == month_ids[i]].copy()
        month_df.drop('month_id', axis=1, inplace=True)
        print(month_df.shape)
        np.stack(X_processed, month_df)
        print(X_processed.shape)
```

Comment: It sounds like your input size should be 30x26. Usually you want to run each sample separately through the network.

Comment: failes as got error or your model didn't converge? Did you try LSTM yet? Add the model summary.